# Does cv::Point3f assignment operator do a "deep" copy?

Tags: c++, opencv

The following class method `Augmented3dPoint::getWorldPoint()` returns a reference to its member `cv::Point3f world_point;`

```
class Augmented3dPoint {
private:
    cv::Point3f world_point;

public:
    cv::Point3f& getWorldPoint () {
        return world_point;
    }
};
```

I am calling this in `main()` through the following code (totalPointCloud is `std::vector<Augmented3dPoint> totalPointCloud;`)

```
cv::Point3f f;
f = totalPointCloud[i].getWorldPoint(); // <---- Probably "deep" copy applied, why?
f.x = 300; // Try to change a value to see if it is reflected on the original world_point
f = totalPointCloud[i].getWorldPoint();

std::cout << f.x << f.y << f.z << std::endl; // The change is not reflected 
//and I get as the result the original world_point,
//which means f is another copy of world_point with 300 in X coordinate
```

What I want to do is achieve the minimum copying of variables. But, the previous code apparently does a "deep" copy...

**a)** Is that correct or there is another explanation?

**b)** I have tried the following

```
cv::Point3f& f = totalPointCloud[i].getWorldPoint();
f.x = 300;
f = totalPointCloud[i].getWorldPoint();
std::cout << f.x << f.y << f.z << std::endl;
```

which seems to directly affect class member variable world_point and avoids a "deep" copy, since its X coordinate is now 300. Is there any other way around?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't think about *deep* or *shallow* copies. Think about either copies or references. You copy the point, you get a fresh, new one. You make a reference to a point, you can refer to that very point. I don't really get what you want to achieve by asking "*Is there any other way around?*". You seem to have found the solution - use a *reference* if you want to alias the original field.

Comment: I am probably totally confused by the cv::Mat assignment operators (I have used them a lot more), which do not copy the actual Mat in a statement like ```cv::Mat m2; m2 = m1;```

Comment: Yeah, it can be confusing, but the default behaviour is to *copy* on *copy-constructors*.

Comment: ```cv::Mat m2; m2 = m1;``` wouldn't be a copy-constructor, right? But an _assignment-operator_

Comment: Correct. Nonetheless their behaviour should be consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a) Is that correct or there is another explanation?

Seems correct although, not necessarily framed in a helpful way. You need to just think of a `Point3f` as a value. When you get the value, you get the value not a reference to it.
Which leads me to

> b) Is there any other way around?

Not really, if you want a reference to a value, you can either use a reference to it, a pointer to it or a wrapper type with the same semantics as a reference or pointer.

So things like

```
cv::Point3f& f = totalPointCloud[i].getWorldPoint();
cv::Point3f* f1 = &totalPointCloud[i].getWorldPoint();
std::reference_wrapper<cv::Point3f> f2 = std::ref(totalPointCloud[i].getWorldPoint());
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Peter. It makes sense atm for ```cv::Point3f```. My biggest concern is if I use/meet another class/library implementing Points/Vectors, like eigen, how can I be 100% sure about what it does? Isn't it possible that a statement like ```xyz::Point3 f; f = getFrom();``` will do a plain _reference_ assignment in the background?

Comment: Well sadly you can't make any definitive claim about this. Whether a type behaves like a value type (i.e. `std::vector`) or like a reference type (i.e.`std::shared_ptr`) can only really be found out by reading the documentation or the source code. You might get some definitive answers when you're dealing with POD types. Then you might use traits like `std::is_pod` to confirm that it's a value type. But the cases where you can ask which one it is inside the program are probably more the exception than the rule.